# A sufficient condition for automorphism of an exact sequence

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers, short-exact-sequences, associative-algebras

I asked [A sufficient condition for Automorphism of an exact sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397443/a-sufficient-condition-for-automorphism-of-an-exact-sequence) earlier on Math.StackExchange but did not get any response so am posting it here.

I am given the following commutative diagram with **non-split** exact rows with $L$, $M$, $N$ being finite dimensional $A$ modules where $A$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0 @>>> L @>f>> M @>g>> N @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVuV @VVvV @VVwV @. \\
0 @>>> L @>>f> M @>>g> N @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$

where $L$ is an indecomposable module.

The claim is: If $w$ is an automorphism then so is $v$ and $u$.

This is **Lemma 5.4.7.** in the book [*An introduction to quiver representations*](https://doi.org/10.1090/gsm/184) by Derksen.

The author claims that by taking $w^{-1}$ and considering the appropriate fibered product we can assume that $w = 1_{N}$.

I don't understand this.

Basically he is saying it is enough to prove the claim for $w = I_{N}$.

**My attempt:** Assume the result is true for $w = I_{N}$. Then we get that for any $v$ such that $g \circ v = g$ implies $v$ is an automorphism. (This is also an isolated condition called $g$ is right minimal map.)

But how to use this to show that for any $w$ if there is a $v$ such that $w \circ g = g \circ v$ then $v$ is an automorphism? I don't see how to write this condition in the above form: $g$ composed with something on the right equals $g$.

This is also lemma 1.12. in Assem's book [Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of/ayNHpi3tYhQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover). There also the author only mentions that it is enough to prove for $w = 1_{N}$.

**Update**: Essentially the same proof that works for $w = 1_{N}$ also works for any automorphism $w$. But still I would like to know how it is sufficient to assume right from the start that $w = 1_{N}$. The author seems to suggest that logically it is correct to assume that $w= 1_{N}$ not just that the same proof goes through for any automorphism $w$.

Comment: When $M = L \oplus N$, you could take $w = I_N$ and $u = 0$ and $v = 0 \oplus I$, and the claim is manifestly false. Are you sure you read the statement correctly?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd sorry, I forgot to mention that the sequence is non-split!